# How to change console language in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line

I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 in Russian.
But I want the console to be in English.
I tried adding the following line to ~/.bachrc but it didn't help.

```
LC_ALL = "en_US.utf8"
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Setting variables in `bash` there should not be any spaces, and locales are case-sensitive `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 1):

From Ubuntu 18.04 upwards, you should issue `localectl status` to see the current locale and change it with `sudo localectl set-locale en_US.UTF-8`.

From the manual: This takes one locale such as `en_US.UTF-8`, or takes one or more locale assignments such as `LANG=de_DE.utf8`, `LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.utf8`, and so on. If one locale without variable name is provided, then `LANG=` locale variable will be set. See man `locale` for details on the available settings and their meanings. Use `list-locales` for a list of available locales.

Reboot is required.